# Rotate an object relative to the player to face another object

Tags: unity, mathematics, rotation

Essentially, in my game, I have 3 objects: a player, a shield and a puck.
I want to have the shield orbit the player to automatically face the puck. (So the position will change with the rotation).

`Transform.LookAt()` works for having the shield look at the puck, but I can't seem to figure out the mathematical wizardry required to apply that rotation to the relative position of the player.

```cs
public class Shield : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject playerObject;

    private GameObject puck;
    private Vector3 offset;
    
    void Start()
    {
        GetPuckObject();
        offset = transform.position - playerObject.transform.position;
    }
    
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = playerObject.transform.position + offset;

        if (!puck)
        {
            if (!GetPuckObject())
                return;
        }
        
        transform.LookAt(puck.transform);
    }

    bool GetPuckObject()
    {
        puck = GameObject.FindWithTag("Puck");
        return puck;
    }
}
```

I feel so dumb for asking for help with this and I'm sure it's been asked before but I can't find anything which yields the behaviour I describe (possibly because I'm struggling to describe it). I think it's a case of translating the rotation to a position but not sure how to approach this.

**Edit**
This moves in relation to the rotation but doesn't work properly past 180 degrees (and is questionable before that)

```cs
  void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!puck)
        {
            transform.position = playerObject.transform.position + offset;
            if (!GetPuckObject())
                return;
        }
        transform.position = playerObject.transform.position + offset;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(puck.transform.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = lookRotation;
        transform.Translate(transform.forward);
        Debug.Log(transform.forward);
    }
```

Comment: I suspect a diagram would help here.

Answer (score 2):

The relative distance between the shield and the player is a fixed length instead of a fixed offset. Record this fixed length and calculate the position according to the rotation.

[image]

```
public class Shield : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject playerObject;

    private GameObject puck;
    private float offset;

    void Start()
    {
        GetPuckObject();
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!puck)
        {
            if (!GetPuckObject())
                return;
        }
        var lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(puck.transform.position - transform.position);
        transform.position = playerObject.transform.position + lookRotation * (Vector3.forward * offset);
        transform.rotation = lookRotation;
    }

    bool GetPuckObject()
    {
        puck = GameObject.FindWithTag("Puck");
        offset = (transform.position - playerObject.transform.position).magnitude;
        return puck;
    }
}
```